# select data from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

tbl1 table

```
user_id amount
1       100
1       200
```

tbl2 table

```
user_id amount
1       900
1       800
```

I need to get the SUM of "amount" column from this tables for some user_id.

I can do it with 2 queries:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS sum1 FROM tbl1 WHERE user_id = 1

SELECT SUM(amount) AS sum2 FROM tbl2 WHERE user_id = 1
```

How can I do it in 1 query?

The output should be:

```
sum1 sum2
300  1700
```

Comment: How do you want the result look like?

Comment: What's the desired output? two columns, one with 300 and one with 1700?

Comment: Please add the desired result of this combined query to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(amount) AS sum1 FROM tbl1 WHERE user_id = 1) as amount1,
       (SELECT SUM(amount) AS sum2 FROM tbl2 WHERE user_id = 1) as amount2;
```

If you wanted to do this efficiently for multiple users, you could do:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM tbl1 t WHERE t.user_id = u.user_id) as amount1,
       (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM tbl2 t WHERE t.user_id = u.user_id) as amount2
FROM (SELECT 1 as user_id UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 as user_id
     ) u
```

This would be efficient if you had indexes on `tbl1(user_id, amount)` and `tbl2(user_id, amount)`.